# PostgreSQL Database Schema: Mapping a shared object to multiple higher-level objects

Tags: database, postgresql, schema

**Background**: I am creating an application that allows users to comment on different object types. For simplicity sake, say I have *Object A* and *Object B*, both of which can be commented on. I want to store those comments in a database table. The data structure for comments for both objects is exactly the same, and the most common db query will be "get all comments for a specific *Object A*".

**Question**: Which of the following schemas would be most effective:

1. A single table, Comments, with a column for "Type"
2. Multiple tables, Comments_ObjectA and Comments_ObjectB, for each object type
3. Something else I haven't considered

**Example Usage**

1. Single table: "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE type="ObjectA" and id_object=123
2. Multiple tables: "SELECT * FROM comment_objecta WHERE id_objecta=123"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Definitely 1. And yes, question looks like a duplicate.

Comment: @muistooshort - they are slightly different scenarios, though very similar. The question you referenced deals with commenting on multiple "pages" in a website, but where pages is the only object that needs commenting. In my example, I will have many instances of several different objects, all of which will require commenting.

Comment: "Different pages" vs "different objects", there's little difference really, you have comment threads and things that have comment threads. I'd add a thread ID to your tables for your various commentable things and FK that to your thread, then comments are linked to threads similarly. If you really have no need for a separate "thread" concept then you have your "single table" solution.

Comment: @muistooshort thank you for your help, I am going to go with the thread concept.